# unusual Logic behind how order numbers are incrementing

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, eav

I'm curious about the logic behind how magento increments it's order numbers, especially regarding orders from different stores within the same website.

We have four stores and have received orders on three of them, all of which are incrementing up from a different point.

Eg.

US store: 100000001

UK store: 1000000001

IE store: 300000001

Is there any logic behind how these numbers start, why would the UK store order numbers begin from 1 billion, the US from 100 million and IE 300 million. I would have thought the UK would be 200 million or something.

Interestingly the first UK order was made less than a minute after an order on the US store.

I should also mention that before going live we deleted some test orders with the [SiteClue_Delete_Orders](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-8.html) module.

Why are they in a different sequence at all?

Can I edit that order numbers directly in the eav_entity_store table?  Would that effect how Magento connects with our Payment Gateways, Braintree & Paypal?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like a mistake in the `eav_entity_store` table. Can you post a screenshot of the data in that table?

Comment: @SanderMangel, I don't have access to it right now, will post it tomorrow. Do you mean a mistake just for the UK store, or the US & IE ones also. Out of interest could I edit the order numbers directly in the eav_entity_store table.  Also I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Posted an answer with a little more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Sander Mangel I was able to figure this out by looking at the `eav_entity_store` table.

[image]

Magento basically adds 100 million to the `increment_prefix` which seems to be based on the `store_id`, as we tried out multiple website/store architectures this is why we had an `increment_prefix` of 10 for one of our stores, which caused those order numbers to start at 1 billion.

Answer (score 2):

Each store should have a unique starting number. So it sounds someone manually changed these numbers.

You can edit the settings yourself, by editing the `increment_prefix` in the `eav_entity_store` table. Also edit the `increment_last_id` to reflect the change.

However, when dealing with Payment Service Providers like paypal they generally check if the order IDs are running up and are not yet used.
So make sure, if you edit the `increment_last_id` value, it's higher than the previous one.

Comment: Just thinking could it be that the increment prefex is created everytime a new store is created, counting up by 100 million each time.  We may have created a few different stores early in development when trying out different store architectures, that may have caused this.

Comment: @Holy ahhh ok now I get it. Then one is `1` and one is `10`. But that's fine. Sorry, took me some time to realize :)